# How I can use html tags with bootstrap in asp.net mvc for get a result from controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Hey Guys I have a problem with my ASP.NET MVC Application. I want to make a Search textfield and a image button in my application. If I input a valu in the textfield I want use this value for search in a list and send the result to the View. I use bootstrap because it looks fine.

here is my code: Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "HomeController"))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Suche</h2>
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="  search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" name="txtSearch" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                            <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string txt)
{

    List<string> petList = new List<string>();
    petList.Add(txt);

    ViewBag.liste = petList;

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input does not have a `name` attribute that matches the parameter in the method so it is not bound. Change it to

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="..." name="txt" />
```

or change the method to match the current `name` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string txtSearch)
```

Side note: Assuming your controller is named `HomeController` then it should be `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))`, not `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "HomeController"))` (which would only work if you have a controller named `HomeControllerController`)